# Export button component Product grid not working "A joined field with this alias is already declared" in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, product-grid

> I have added ExportButton on admin product grid and when i click on
> export it shows error Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A joined field with
> this alias is already declared.

[image]